# Macbook freezes (keyboard, mouse, audio not working) with external hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, crash, performance

I've installed some apps on external hard drive, as I don't have enough space on my macbook's drive. Sadly macbook behaves really weirdly few times a day.
Basically it freezes completely (although youtube video is still playing if it happens) and I cannot do anything - mouse, keyboard, touchpad are not working and I only can turn it of by pressing power button for a longer time.
I think it happens only when something runs from that external drive.
My macbook info:
[image]

External drive info:
`Samsung 1TB M3 Portable 2,5''`
It uses NTFS  but I used Samsung's `NTFS_for_Mac_11.3` software to have read/write permissions.
Console logs:

```
Mar  2 14:57:23 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
Mar  2 14:57:23 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: IPv6 packet filtering initialized, default to accept, logging disabled
Mar  2 14:57:23 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Mar  2 14:57:23 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 1
Mar  2 14:57:23 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en0::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
Mar  2 14:57:23 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: ARPT: 10.218859: AWDL Sync Enabled 0
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: ARPT: 10.542059: MacAuthEvent en0   Auth result for: 64:66:b3:fa:78:d8  MAC AUTH succeeded
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en0
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 64:66:b3:fa:78:d8
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 13
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en0::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: ARPT: 10.549983: AWDL Sync Enabled 0
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en0
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local blued[83]: Acquired the wifi lock
Mar  2 14:57:24 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local blued[83]: Release the WiFi lock
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[38]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1709] en0: SSID 'DOMDOMI_02' making interface primary (protected network)
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local configd[46]: network changed: v4(en4:172.20.10.3) DNS* Proxy SMB
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[38]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Evaluating
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[38]: Captive: en0: Probing 'DOMDOMI_02'
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local configd[46]: network changed: v4(en0!:192.168.1.101, en4) DNS! Proxy SMB
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local networkd[191]: +[NETLedBelly stopFastFail] Clearing ledbelly failure cache
Mar  2 14:57:26 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 64:66:b3:fa:78:d8
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 13
Mar  2 14:57:26 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[38]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Authenticated
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[229]: User info context values set for piotr
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.FileSyncAgent.PHD.isRunning): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbloginhelper.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbpluginhost.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[229]: Login Window login proceeding
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[91]: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[91]: USER_PROCESS: 91 console
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleKeyStore:Sending lock change 0 for handle -501
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.FileSyncAgent.PHD.isRunning): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbloginhelper.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:28 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbpluginhost.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.AssistiveControl.running): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.btsa): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.coreservices.lsactivity): Unknown key for Boolean: DrainMessagesAfterFailedInit
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.coreservices.uiagent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.diagnostics_agent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dock.fullscreen): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dock.server): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dock.notificationcenter): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dock.appstore): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dock.remotedesktoppicture): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dock.launchpad): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dock.downloads): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert): Unknown key for string: seatbelt-profiles
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Finder): ThrottleInterval set to zero. You're not that important. Ignoring.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.FontRegistryUIAgent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ATS.FontValidator): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ATS.FontValidatorConduit): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.gamed): The JetsamProperties key is not available on this platform.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.gamed): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.gamed): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.helpd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.installd.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua): Caller tried to hijack service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.mbpluginhost.user.plist, caller = loginwindow.91
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.midiserver.io): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.noticeboard.agent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.notificationcenterui.alerts): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.notificationcenterui.tcc): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.notificationcenterui.agent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua): Caller tried to hijack service: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.pluginkit.pkd.plist, caller = loginwindow.91
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.PubSub.Agent): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper.active): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ReportCrash): The DrainMessagesOnCrash key is not yet implemented. If you rely on this key, please file a bug.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ReportCrash.Self): The DrainMessagesOnCrash key is not yet implemented. If you rely on this key, please file a bug.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.rtcreportingd): The UserName key is not supported for non-System services.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.SafariCloudHistoryPushAgent): The UserName key is not supported for non-System services.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sharingd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.soagent): Invalid type for event (event/type): events/array
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.soagent): Invalid type for event (event/type): bundleid/string
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.speech.speechdatainstallerd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ssinvitationagent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemuiserver.ServiceProvider): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dockextra.server): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.SUISMessaging): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ipodserver): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemuiserver.screencapture): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.tsm.uiserver): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.dockling.server): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.window_proxies.startup): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.window_proxies): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.inputswitcher.running): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.universalaccesscontrol.running): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.universalaccessd.running): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.usernoted): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.VoiceOver.running): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ZoomWindow.running): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.openbsd.ssh-agent): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.bjango.istatmenusagent): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.bjango.istatmenusnotifications): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.bjango.istatmenusstatus): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.brother.LOGINserver): Please switch away from OnDemand to KeepAlive.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (net.juniper.pulsetray): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.pluginkit.pkd.plist, error = 17: File exists
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.mbpluginhost.user.plist, error = 17: File exists
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local distnoted[264]: # distnote server agent  absolute time: 15.314308579   civil time: Wed Mar  2 14:57:29 2016   pid: 264 uid: 501  root: no
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oculusvr.ovrserver): The Debug key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local otherbsd[263]: Failed to bootstrap agent: path = /Users/piotr/Library/LaunchAgents/org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist, error = 119: Service is disabled
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oculusvr.ovrserver): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.spotify.webhelper): Unknown key for string: SpotifyPath
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x746054c5: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 35 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 9d1, Model 8002, S/N 5445, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x108b8b6375430ad5c22edc7c72a7c5dd, ColorSpace { -2068572970 }
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003ddb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (4224, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7f92cbc1b740) - enabling OpenGL
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003ddb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (4225, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (1920, 0)[1280 x 800], 27 modes available
    Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { -180317613 }
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.spotify.webhelper): The NetworkState key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003ddb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.valvesoftware.steamclean): Unknown key for array: SteamContentPaths
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.DataDetectorsDynamicData): The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner): The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[262]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 0.250 second wait for reply from "loginwindow" for synchronous notification type 100 (kCGSDisplayWillReconfigure) (CID 0x8207, PID 91)
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -login
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[262]: com.apple.TMHelperAgent.SetupOffer enabled
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local lsregister[267]: LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local lsregister[267]: LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[262]: user agent networkd: built May 12 2015 20:37:54
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x746054c5: Unit 1: Startup Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80001000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1280 x 800, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80001000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x746054c5: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 35 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 9d1, Model 8002, S/N 5445, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x108b8b6375430ad5c22edc7c72a7c5dd, ColorSpace { -2068572970 }
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003ddb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (4224, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003ddb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (4225, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (1920, 39)[1280 x 800], 27 modes available
    Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf, ColorSpace { -180317613 }
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003ddb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x746054c5 device: 0x7f92cbe16310  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280600 device: 0x7f92cbd07780  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local DMProxy[272]: AMBD Services: connection interrupted: com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (Connection interrupted)
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: AMBD initializing devices
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: CGSGetSizeOfDisplayTransfer: Invalid display 0x00000001
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: CGSSetDisplayIntention: Invalid display 0x00000001
Mar  2 14:57:29 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: CGSSetDisplayIntentionWiper: Invalid display 0x00000001
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[262]: received an unknown event from daemon
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local apsd[73]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
Mar  2 14:57:29 --- last message repeated 7 times ---
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x746054c5: Unit 1; ColorProfile { -180317613 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[185]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { -180317613 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[215]: AMBD Agent: xpc connection became invalid during event handler
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local blued[83]: Logging disabled
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.FileSyncAgent.PHD.isRunning): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local secinitd[297]: UID[501]: cache loaded: /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.app-sandbox-cache.plist
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbloginhelper.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbpluginhost.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.SecurityServer[77]: Session 100010 created
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local apsd[73]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.DataDetectorsDynamicData): The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro.local apsd[73]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
Mar  2 14:57:29 Piotrs-MacBook-Pro askpermissiond[305]: objc[305]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I see that line `com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ReportCrash): The DrainMessagesOnCrash key is not yet implemented. If you rely on this key, please file a bug.` every time it happens.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Does this drive _need_ to be formatted with NTFS? You don't mention if you share this drive with any Windows-based CPUs. If this drive connects to Windows, then edit your question (or comment) to that effect. If this drive is only used on this (and other Mac OS X systems) then reformat with Disk Utility using Mac OS X Journaled.

Comment: It's not used on Windows. But why/how OSX Journaled format will fix my issue?

Comment: Formatting Journaled is the standard disk formatting method for OS X and was not mentioned as a solution to the issue: not using NTFS _will_ fix the issue. If you don't need NTFS at all, don't use it!

Comment: Yeah... I meant using Journaled format INSTEAD of NTFS... So is it something which looks like poor support for NTFS on OSXs related issue?

Comment: [Apple does include limited NTFS support](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-enable-ntfs-write-support-natively-for-os-x/), but most NTFS disks need 3rd party software to work more reliably than Apple's drivers. Some NTFS implementations are better than others, but if you'll never need to connect this drive to a Windows machine, you're better off with the native OS X format. You didn't mention what kind of interface this drive hangs from. USB? FireWire 400/800? Thunderbolt?

Comment: It's USB. I reformatted it to Mac OS X Journaled and I still see that macbook freezes

Comment: It is probably a hardware issue then. Are the same errors showing up in the log-files? What are you doing with the drive that causes it to freeze the Mac? Just plugging it in? Reading/Writing files? Opening apps?

Comment: Do you mean issue is on macbook or external drive side? It happened only once since reformat and I don't see it in logs, but will check it next time. So it mostly happens during write operations, e.g. one of the apps installed on that drive creates some new files or I am downloading something on it

Comment: Does this drive fail no matter which USB port you use on the MPB? The only way to test is to get (or borrow) a known-working external USB drive, or test this misbehaving drive on somebody else's Mac.

Comment: It fails on every USB port. I have used different drive before and I haven't noticed that issue

Comment: Sounds like the drive, the electronics, or both, are not working correctly. If the drive has a detachable USB cable, remove it and experiment with a known-good USB cable. It's the last thing you can try before opening up the case and removing the HD.

Comment: @IconDaemon I've replaced original dual-female USB cable with different single one and I don't see freezing any more... Really weird.

Comment: Ah. Usually a dual USB cable is to provide additional power to the drive which requires more current than can be provided from a single USB port. Looking at the specs for this drive, I see that it is a USB3 device. Is this an earlier model with USB2?

Comment: It's USB3 but somehow working. Should I buy new dual cable or can I use this one?

Comment: If this cable is working then use it!

Comment: Thanks. You can post an answer about checking USB cable and I can accept it and give you points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible the the USB cable will prove to be the culprit. An inexpensive test is to use another cable that you know works on other disks. If the disk mounts and does not crash your Macbook, then the old cable is suspect. You should probably recycle it.